# where is move_arm_msgs on ROS electric?

Tags: ros, move-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run

```
  roscreate-pkg move_arm_to_the_goal_test roscpp actionlib move_arm_msgs
```

but it says:

```
  ERROR: dependency [move_arm_msgs] cannot be found
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11696/where-is-move_arm_msgs-on-ros-electric?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are now included in [arm_navigation_msgs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation_msgs)

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just ran the following set of commands at the root of my source tree:

```
perl -e "s/motion_planning_msgs/arm_navigation_msgs/g;" -pi $(find -type f)
perl -e "s/move_arm_msgs/arm_navigation_msgs/g;" -pi $(find -type f)
perl -e "s/collision_environment_msgs/arm_navigation_msgs/g;" -pi $(find -type f)
perl -e "s/planning_environment_msgs/arm_navigation_msgs/g;" -pi $(find -type f)
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-10-27**:
Another Martin's perl :-)